# How can one see the structure of a table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

How can I see the structure of table in [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) as `desc` was in Oracle?

Answer (score 392, accepted):

Invoke the `sqlite3` utility on the database file, and use its special dot commands:

- `.tables` will list tables
- `.schema [tablename]` will show the CREATE statement(s) for a table or tables

There are many other useful builtin dot commands -- see the documentation at http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html, section **Special commands to sqlite3**.

Example:

```
sqlite> entropy:~/Library/Mail>sqlite3 Envelope\ Index
SQLite version 3.6.12
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
addresses              ews_folders            subjects
alarms                 feeds                  threads
associations           mailboxes              todo_notes
attachments            messages               todos
calendars              properties             todos_deleted_log
events                 recipients             todos_server_snapshot
sqlite> .schema alarms
CREATE TABLE alarms (ROWID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, alarm_id,
                     todo INTEGER, flags INTEGER, offset_days INTEGER,
                     reminder_date INTEGER, time INTEGER, argument,
                     unrecognized_data BLOB);
CREATE INDEX alarm_id_index ON alarms(alarm_id);
CREATE INDEX alarm_todo_index ON alarms(todo);
```

Note also that SQLite saves the schema and all information about tables in the database itself, in a magic table named *sqlite_master*, and it's also possible to execute normal SQL queries against that table. For example, the documentation link above shows how to derive the behavior of the `.schema` and `.tables` commands, using normal SQL commands (see section: **Querying the database schema**).

Comment: one common mistake here is confusing these utility functions with sql statements.. the former doesn't require a `;` at the end of the command where as the latter does.

Comment: Doesn't show me the index for me even though I have a primary key on two columns together

Comment: doesn't work for me but the answer by AnonGeek does

Comment: .tables and .schema display only "the original CREATE TABLE and CREATE INDEX statements". Any subsequent changes will NOT be reflected. You should really use PRAGMA table_info(table_name) instead.

Comment: @Blago: Even though EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN shows an autoindex on my table, PRAGMA table_info(table_name) doesn't show the autoindex. However I think that must be because sqlite "created an automatic index that lasts only for the duration of a single SQL statement". (https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#automatic_indexes)

Comment: `.schema users;` doesn't show anything for me. the table exists though.

Comment: @chovy try `.schema users`  instead of `.schema users;` (everyone in general that this is not working for might want to try this too)

Comment: Weird. It worked. Thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 438):

```
PRAGMA table_info(table_name);
```

This will work for both: command-line and when executed against a connected database.

A link for more details and example. thanks
[SQLite Pragma Command](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html)

Comment: execute `.header on` before execute above command. you can view columns with data.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. .tables and .schema display only "the original CREATE TABLE and CREATE INDEX statements". Any subsequent changes will NOT be reflected.

Comment: If you want to get the table info for an attached database 'foo', you run `PRAGMA foo.table_info(table_name);`

Comment: This will also show the underlying structure of virtual tables. (http://sqlite.org/vtab.html)

Answer (score 51):

You can query [`sqlite_schema`](https://www.sqlite.org/schematab.html) (which was historically called `sqlite_master`).

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_schema WHERE name='foo';
```

which will return a `create table` SQL statement, for example:

```
$ sqlite3 mydb.sqlite
sqlite> create table foo (id int primary key, name varchar(10));
sqlite> select sql from sqlite_schema where name='foo';
CREATE TABLE foo (id int primary key, name varchar(10))

sqlite> .schema foo
CREATE TABLE foo (id int primary key, name varchar(10));

sqlite> pragma table_info(foo)
0|id|int|0||1
1|name|varchar(10)|0||0
```

Answer (score 20):

You should be able to see the schema by running

```
.schema <table>
```

Answer (score 14):

.schema TableName

Where TableName is the name of the Table

Answer (score 11):

You will get the structure by typing the command:

```
.schema <tableName>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHP you can get it this way:

```
<?php
    $dbname = 'base.db';
    $db = new SQLite3($dbname);
    $sturturequery = $db->query("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE name='foo'");

    $table = $sturturequery->fetchArray();
    echo '<pre>' . $table['sql'] . '</pre>';

    $db->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Firefox add-on called [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager-webext/?src=search) to view the database's structure clearly.