# sqlite3 from windows command promt

Tags: sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE texhisowntable (age INTEGER,  name (32));
```

in this emty TABLE i write infomation. First age, Second name up to 32, (string, numbers, ore chars i don't know witch one you would try, but i write Words )
..so lets do it:

```
INSERT INTO texhisowntable (age, name) VALUES(100, ''TheJavaRockS>|<RwithTheGoldenAxE");
```

so now im TheJavaRockS>|

```
SELECT * FROM texhisowntable;
```

and my command would say:"ACDC, let it Play, you are old but you look fine"
//he would print :   TheJavaRockS>|

but im old and i forget things, so who knows how i can see, how i created the table.

I only want rom the commandprommt he print's

```
CREATE TABLE texhisowntable (age INTEGER,  name (32));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How i can see the structure of table in sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654762/how-i-can-see-the-structure-of-table-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

13 ago, i answer my own Question. With the command ".schema"  it shows every table for example in the file "thnkhsu.db"  where also the TABLE "texhisowntable" is.

If you got much TABLES,  and search only, the one you like, for example the  "texhisowntable" in the file "thnkhsu.db" you only need to write
".schemas  texhisowntable" and the command shows, how  i created the TABLE.

;) its very simple