# PHP PDO + Sqlite, show indexes on table

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm trying to show the indexes on a table using sqlite and PHP.

The manual here ( https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html ) suggests:

`.indexes ?TABLE?`

However, using

`$pdo->query('.indexes my_table');`

Shows:

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ".": syntax error`

Is it possible to execute these dot commands using PHP and PDO?

edit: example code:

```
    $this->pdo->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test');
    $this->pdo->query('CREATE TABLE test (id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, col1 text NOT NULL, col2 text NOT NULL)');
    $this->pdo->query('CREATE INDEX col1 ON test (col1)');
    $result = $this->pdo->query('PRAGMA table_info(test);')->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    print_r($result);
```

This does not show the indexes. The following errors:

```
    $this->pdo->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test');
    $this->pdo->query('CREATE TABLE test (id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, col1 text NOT NULL, col2 text NOT NULL)');
    $this->pdo->query('CREATE INDEX col1 ON test (col1)');
    $result = $this->pdo->query('.indexes test')->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    print_r($result);
```

This returns an empty array:

```
    $this->pdo->query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test');
    $this->pdo->query('CREATE TABLE test (id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, col1 text NOT NULL, col2 text NOT NULL)');
    $this->pdo->query('CREATE INDEX index_col1 ON test (col1)');
    $result = $this->pdo->query('PRAGMA index_info(test);')->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    print_r($result);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one see the structure of a table in sqlite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654762/how-can-one-see-the-structure-of-a-table-in-sqlite)

Comment: [See the top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8050126/250076)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not show the indexes, only the column types. I have updated the question with example code

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thought that was equivalent? What about `PRAGMA index_list(table-name)`? I've added it to my answer

Comment: aha! Thank you! Yes, I had tried index_info which I'd seen elsewhere but that didn't work. The command is index_list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to execute these dot commands using PHP and PDO?

No, they only work in the SQLite command line interface.

> I'm trying to show the indexes on a table using sqlite and PHP.

```
PRAGMA index_list(table-name)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-- List all indexes
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'index';
-- List all indexes on table XXX
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'index' and tbl_name = 'XXX';
```