# showing "table" as an invalid syntax in Python 3.5 using sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, python-3.5

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute(CREATE table Movies(index integer, mvnm text, year integer, genere text))
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

It highlights `table` in red color.

Answer (score 2):

There are few problems:

- The SQL should be provided in quotes because the execute() method accepts a
  string argument.
- `index` is a reserved keyword in SQL, so you cannot use
  that as the name of your column.
- If you want to run this script
  repeatedly, you should add `IF NOT EXISTS` clause. Otherwise
  consequent runs will fail due to "table already exists"

So, after these changes the statement looks like below:

```
c.execute("CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS Movies(myindex integer, mvnm text, year integer, genere text)")
```

You can then verify the table creation by logging in to sqllite:

```
$> ~ $ sqlite3 example.db
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
Movies
```

Comment: Thanks, for a newbie to sqlite3 and python it was really getting tedious. I ran 
c.execute("CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS Movies(myindex integer, mvnm text, year integer, genere text)")
and instantly got this
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x033E9060> 
I guess that is confirmation itself.
In addition to this, I have one more question sqlite3 comes built in python 3, meaning I do not have to separately install sqlite3 module using pip. so how do I verify it, where should I run that command? In python idle?

Comment: Yes, it does come builtin. I usually run `python -c "import sqlite3"` in a shell to verify if a module is available. A little faster than doing the same in the idle shell

Comment: No No! I'm talking about 
$> ~ $ sqlite3 example.db
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
Movies

Where should I run the first command so as to know which sqlite3 version do i have and access Movies table? In command prompt or Python idle shell? Sorry if its annoying you!

Comment: That would be at the command prompt. To know the version, run `sqlite3 -version`. This assumes you have it in the path. Also, see this post for querying etc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654762/how-can-one-see-the-structure-of-a-table-in-sqlite?rq=1