# Accessing the dot cli commands from sqlite in pysqlite

Tags: sqlite, pysqlite

I'm looking to access the sqlite dot commands in pysql, particularly the

```
.tables
.schema
.import
```

commands.  However, when I try:

```
>>> db.execute(".tables")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pysqlite3.dbapi2.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error
```

What is the syntax that allows this?

#### not a dupe explained in comment

Comment: The `.tables` etc commands are built into the command line client of SQLite, but you can use the equivalent SQL statements to get at the schema information. Importing must be done manually. `SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE name='foo';`See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654762/how-can-one-see-the-structure-of-a-table-in-sqlite

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one see the structure of a table in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654762/how-can-one-see-the-structure-of-a-table-in-sqlite)

Comment: Not a dupe of that. I know how to do that with a select query. I was asking specifically for a variety of dot commands (not just .schema) which are more succinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Corion said in his comment, the `sqlite3` dot commands are a feature of the `sqlite3` command-line utility *only*, not the SQL dialect supported by SQLite3.  Therefore if you want to get the effect of running these commands in your own program, you have to actually implement those yourself using the publically available SQLite3 functions.